# How do I add methods to Date, String, Array, Number Etc in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How do I tell TypeScript of additions to native types like Date,Number,String etc?

E.g. I want the following to compile (example from http://sugarjs.com/dates):

```
var date: Date = Date.create('tomorrow'); // I get a compile error
date.isAfter('March 1st') // I get a compile error
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two kinds of extensions needed here.

## 1.) Static members addition to native types

e.g. `create` in the given example.

This can be done by adding to `<type>Constructor` interfaces. e.g.

```
interface DateConstructor {
    create(query: string): Date;
}
```

## 2.) Instance member additions to native types

e.g. `isAfter` in the given example.

This can be done by adding to `<type>` interface e.g.

```
interface Date {
    isAfter(query: string): boolean;
}
```

## Complete example

```
interface DateConstructor {
    create(query: string): Date;
}
interface Date {
    isAfter(query: string): boolean;
}

var date: Date = Date.create('tomorrow'); // okay
date.isAfter('March 1st') // okay
```

This has been possible since TypeScript `1.4`.

Comment: Thanks a lot basarat. Big help.

Comment: Seeing a few problems with this complete example though, both now on existing Date data type and create still not being found. http://screencloud.net/v/ailu

Comment: The interfaces need to be at the *root* of your file outside any *internal module*. Otherwise they don't point to the global interfaces get *shadowed* by a *new local* interface. Fix : http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20DateConstructor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20create(query%3A%20string)%3A%20Date%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20Date%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20isAfter(query%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Amodule%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20date%3A%20Date%20%3D%20Date.create('tomorrow')%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0A%20%20%20%20date.isAfter('March%201st')%20%2F%2F%20okay%20%0A%7D

Comment: Ah yes, much better. Thank you, just my lack of understanding of scopes, learning and implementing as I go along :)